# Как заполнить столбец в pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Помогите! Мне нужно перевести одномерный массив в столбец в pandas DataFrame.
Я делаю это вот так:

```
out_put = pd.DataFrame(is_in,['Вхождение'])
```

где `is_in` - одномерный массив. Но получаю я на выходе строку.
Какую магию надо дописать, чтобы получать столбец?

Answer (score 3):

Конструктор `pd.DataFrame()` ожидает в качестве *второго* параметра вектор индексов. Чтобы задать наименование(я) столбцов, укажите имя параметра `columns` явно.

Пример:

```
In [93]: df = pd.DataFrame([10,11,12,13], columns=['Вхождение'])

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
   Вхождение
0         10
1         11
2         12
3         13
```